# Processing, Mirroring or Flipping an Image without affecting others

Tags: javascript, audio, sprite, processing

I'm developing a mini platform game with Processing using Javascript, something like Mario.

I'm moving my character with arrows or WASD and I'd like to know if there's an alternative to `scale(-1,1);` when mirroring the character / image. (It's looking to the right by default or when you press D, and when you press A it flips to left).

If it's the best or easiest way, I'd also like to know **how to make the scale method not to affect all the rest of images**, since I want to put some platforms but with scale they keep flipping while character moves...

I'm also listening to any info related to sprite / sound usage with Processing and Javascript. I've tried some libraries but they only work when I switch to Java mode.

Thanks in advance,
Maral.

I used the scale mirroring thanks to a previous post.
[Processing mirror image over x axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334348/processing-mirror-image-over-x-axis)

"dreta" is Right and "esquerre" is Left, both are controlled with WASD or Keys changing each boolean on press to true and on release to false.
I didn't post all the code but this is the basic movement I wanted to fix.

```
   void draw() {
       pushMatrix();
       if (iniciar == true) {
       inici();
    }
    if (dreta == true && esquerre != true) {
      movDret(backgroundimg[2]);
    }
    if (esquerre == true && dreta != true) {
      movEsquerre(backgroundimg[2]);
    }
  }

   void platformndBackground(PImage b){
      background(b);
      popMatrix();
      image(imgGrass[0], 50, 50);
      if (esquerre == true) {
        scale(-1,1);
      }
   }

   void inici() {
      movDret(backgroundimg[2]);
      iniciar = false;
   }

   void movDret(PImage b) {
      //Colisió extrem Esquerre.
     if (posicio > 1024-imgJugador[5].width) {
       posicio = posicio - imgJugador[tipusMoviment].width/2;
       movEsquerre(backgroundimg[2]);
     } else {
       bothMoviments(b);
       image(imgJugador[tipusMoviment], posicio, posicioSalt);
       posicio = posicio + 3;
     }
   }

    void movEsquerre(PImage b) {
      //Colisió extrem Dret.
      if (posicio < 0) {
        posicio = posicio + imgJugador[tipusMoviment].width/2;
        popMatrix();
        movDret(backgroundimg[2]);
      } else {
        bothMoviments(b);
        image(imgJugador[tipusMoviment], ((-imgJugador[tipusMoviment].width)-posicio), posicioSalt);
        posicio = posicio - 3;
      }
    }

    void bothMoviments(PImage b) {
      if (esquerre == true) {
        scale(-1, 1);
      }else{
        popMatrix();
      }
        if (tipusMoviment < imgJugador.length-1) {
          tipusMoviment++;
        } else {
          tipusMoviment = 5;
        }
        platformndBackground(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mirror your sprite, you could just use two sets of sprites: one for going right and one for going left.

But if you're using the scale() function to mirror your sprite, you need to use `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` so the scale doesn't affect every other sprite. Something like this:

```
public void draw(){

   background(0);

   pushMatrix(); //save current "default" matrix
      scale(-1,1); //scale the matrix
      image(img,-img.width,img.height); //draw the image using the scaled matrix
   popMatrix(); //go back to the saved "default" matrix

   //draw non-mirrored sprites
   image(img2,img2.width,img2.height);
}
```

More info can be found in the reference [here](http://processingjs.org/reference/pushMatrix_/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after some tries and replacing some scales(-1,1) for popMatrix() It's finally working.